# Trying to send image from one php file to another

Tags: php, file, session

I'm making my own sharex host and i'm having some issues.

Firstly, if I upload DIRECTLY to the `upload.php` file, it works without issues. However I want to have another php file which handles the requests and passes them on as i'd like to have multiple domains (it'll basically get the php url and redirect depending on api key used).

The first thing i tried was to just do a simple redirect with the `header()` function in PHP, the file couldn't be transferred when I did this. I did some digging and tried to put `$_FILES` into a var in the `$_SESSION` variable, which also does not work (however I am able to get the name of the file in the upload.php with this method)

I'm not sure what else exactly I can do, i'll provide some code snippets below.

**the "main" php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["file"] = $_FILES;
if(($_GET["apikey"] === "apiKey")) {
   header("Location: https://domain/upload.php?apikey=apiKey");
}
?>
```

**the upload.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$sharexdir = '';
$domain_url = 'https://domain/';
if(!($_GET["apikey"] === "apiKey")){
    header("Location: https://differentDomain/");
    exit;
}
$_file = $_SESSION["file"];
$target_file = $_file["sharex"]["name"];
$fileType = pathinfo($target_file);

if (move_uploaded_file($_file["sharex"]["tmp_name"], $sharexdir/.$target_file)) 
{
    echo '‍'.$domain_url.$sharexdir.substr($target_file, 0, strrpos($target_file, "."));
}
    else
{
   echo 'File upload failed - CHMOD/Folder doesn\'t exist?';
}
?>
```

I appreciate any help, thanks!

NOTE: if using the upload.php directly i have to change `$_SESSION["file"]` to `$_FILES`

Answer (score 0):

"$_FILES" is a global php array that save details of uploaded file by client that saves into your tmp folder of php application

at first you putting your files details in a some sessions index and redirect client to another page. this causes only your files details send to second file and your real uploaded files that save in the "tmp" folder of php removed after done first process (your main.php file)

actually the solution of php for processing uploaded files is this

if you use "print_r" or "var_dump" or any another export functions for your "$_FILES", you can see the each file has a "tmp_name" index that show you the real path of client uploaded file

the php application upload clients uploaded files in its tmp folder to you use the move_uploaded_file function. if you use it or not after finishing process, php deleting all files that uploaded by client in this directory

in your code "the finishing process" statement is in end of "main.php" file. not in "upload.php"

actually client uploaded files to this file (main.php) and after running this file the php application think your process has been done

it's not metter your processes do not done and you forward your client in another files. your upload process is finish after running main.php

so after this description: there is no way. you should use upload.php directly or upload your files in main.php and in upload.php use your local temp files. there is no way for using $_FILES variable for a file in another